# Laravel 5 Eloquent - Relationships return empty array

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

it seems I can't extract the data from my db (mongodb) using eloquent's relationships.

These are my two documents inside the auctions and bids collections:

```
> db.auctions.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f987e7f16e455072d21593"), "bought" : "true", "description" : "Lorem ipsum dolorem sit amet", "dueDate" : "31/12/2015", "position" : 1, "img" : "images/NeoTheMatrix.jpg" }

> db.bids.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55f98e11f16e455072d21594"), "amount" : "500", "company_id" : "55f97ec648177ed4308b456c", "auction_id" : "55f987e7f16e455072d21593" }
```

In the **Auction** model within Laravel, I created a function like this:

```
public function bids(){
    return $this->hasMany('PreventiviVeloci\Bid','auction_id','_id');
}
```

In the **Bid** model, I created another function:

```
public function auctions()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('PreventiviVeloci\Auction','_id');
}
```

When in my view I call it with `$auctions->bids` I get an empty array. Can you help me to spot the error? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, Laravel's database package (and Eloquent, which uses that package) does not support Mongo. According to [the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/database#introduction) only RDBMS systems are supported. IIRC, there *is* a package out there that extends this to Mongo, but I don't remember the name and I've no idea if it works as advertised.

Comment: I think you mean Jenssegers' Mongodb extension, I'm already using it and can extract data from db..so that's not the problem

Comment: You might have mentioned that you're using another package - perhaps the problem is there.